# Android Room - selective query with LiveData

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

Is it possible to get specific rows from Room with LiveData?
My goal is to retrieve certain items from data base, when each item is conditioned by to columns ("page" and "category").
The problem is that in LiveData observer I always receive the same page  - that livedata object had been initiated with it in the beginning.
It has no effect if I change it afterwards in the ViewModel:

```
    private fun requestNextPageFromDB(page: Int) {
    filmsListLiveData = interactor.getPageOfFilmsFromDB(page)
}
```

I create the LiveData object in init block of my ViewModel:

```
var filmsListLiveData: LiveData<List<Film>>

init {
    filmsListLiveData = interactor.getPageOfFilmsFromDB(2)
```

The method in Interactor class I initiate the livedata object:

```
fun getPageOfFilmsFromDB(page: Int): LiveData<List<Film>> =
    repo.getPageOfFilmsInCategoryFromDB(page, getFilmsCategoryFromPreferences())
```

Next method in the repository:

```
fun getPageOfFilmsInCategoryFromDB(page: Int, category: String): LiveData<List<Film>> {
    return filmDao.getCachedFilmsByPageAndCategory(page, category)
}
```

And the last one in the Dao Intertface:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM cached_films WHERE page=:requestedPage AND category=:requestedCategory")
fun getCachedFilmsByPageAndCategory(requestedPage: Int, requestedCategory:String): LiveData<List<Film>>
```

All the methods above are invoked properly when the page number changes in livedata object.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From the description it seems that you are just replacing the `filmsListLiveData` reference, however the observer remains the original one, that is why it is not notified about any changes, since in the original `filmsListLiveData` there have been no changes.

You can use a `MutableLiveData` for the page value and then a `Transformations.switchMap` to obtain a LiveData that will react to the changes of the page value.

Inside your ViewModel, you can do something like this

```
    // starting page is 2, not sure if it should be 1 or 2, I just copied you logic from init
    private val currentPageLiveData = MutableLiveData(2) 
    var filmsListLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(currentPageLiveData) { page ->
        interactor.getPageOfFilmsFromDB(page)
    }

    private fun requestNextPageFromDB(page: Int) {
        currentPageLiveData.value = page
    }

    init {
        // not needed anymore - remove this code
        // filmsListLiveData = interactor.getPageOfFilmsFromDB(2)
    }
```

With that, every time `requestNextPageFromDB(page: Int)` will be called, `currentPageLiveData` value will change, the `switchMap` will get called and a new call to `interactor.getPageOfFilmsFromDB(page)` will be made. That will update the `LiveData` value and your observer will be called again.

So the `switchMap` does exactly what you need, it switches the LiveData behind the scenes every time the source LiveData changes (in this case the currentPageLiveData) in such a way, that existing observers stop observing the old LiveData instance, the one **switched from**, and start observing the new LiveData instance, the one **switched to**.

At this point you can also change **var** `filmsListLiveData` to **val** `filmsListLiveData` and remove all code that is trying to replace its reference, since there is no need to replace this LiveData anymore (now it reacts to the page value change on its own).

Comment: Great, it works! Thank you very much!